# declaring variable length array as macro

Tags: c, arrays, macros

Can on do this:

```
#define VARIABLE_LENGTH_CHAR_ARRAY(name, size) \
                            int temp_array_size_macro_index = size; \
                            char "#name"[temp_array_size_macro_index];
```

and in the main use it like:

```
main(){
    VARIABLE_LENGTH_CHAR_ARRAY(local_char_array, 16);    
}
```

would this go against the coding styles or would it be plagued with macro issues?

I know you need to be careful with the variable name!

Comment: `#name[temp_array_size_macro_index];` - This is going to be the string literal `"name[temp_array_size_macro_index];"`. I don't think you meant that.

Comment: Great way of making program error prone and impossible to read

Comment: It does not make the variables variable length

Comment: Try `gcc -E file.c` to see your code after it was preprocessed.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any point in hiding the declaration of the array behind a macro.  `char local_char_array[16];` is a lot more understandable than `VARIABLE_LENGTH_CHAR_ARRAY(local_char_array, 16);`

Comment: Perhaps *"A Study in Obfuscation"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I am right you want something like that :

```
#define VARIABLE_LENGTH_CHAR_ARRAY(name, size) \
                        const int size_of_##name = size; \
                        char name[size_of_##name]

int main()
{
   VARIABLE_LENGTH_CHAR_ARRAY(local_char_array, 16);
}
```

The name of the (now *const*) variable for the size now depends on the name of the array itself, that minimize the probability to have homonyms

The expansion of that code produced by `gcc -E` gives :

```
int main()
{
   const int size_of_local_char_array = 16; char local_char_array[size_of_local_char_array];
}
```

But to do that it is *strange* :

- as `__J__ I` think this not helps to make the program readable
- else where in your source `size_of_local_char_array`  can be used but if you/someone search for its definition it will not be found
- the macro produces two statements, and of course in that case it is not possible to group them in a block `{}`, this is dangerous because this is not intuitive. As you can see in your code you added a useless ';' after the use of the macro while a final ';' is already present in the macro definition